# Конвертировать MediaStream в base64

Tags: javascript, html, веб-программирование, html5, ecmascript-6

Имею следующий код:

```js
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true, video: false }).then(function(stream){
var voice = stream.getAudioTracks()[0];
});
```

Как мне получить аудио с микрофона, закодировать в base64 для передачи на сервер?